# Update value of attribute which is NULL by querying on that attribute

Tags: mysql, database

I inserted an item in to a table that has three rows (`id`, `text`, `data`) without a `text` attribute.

```
id text date 
4  NULL 2010-11-11
```

I wanted to modify the row by inserting text into this same entry. I tried this:

```
UPDATE x SET text = "This is funny" WHERE text = NULL;
```

I also tried:

```
UPDATE x SET text = "This is funny" WHERE text = "NULL";
```

also:

```
UPDATE x SET text = "This is funny" WHERE text LIKE "NULL";
```

and also:

```
UPDATE x SET text = "This is funny" WHERE text LIKE "%NULL%";
```

None of them seems to do the trick. I know I can use the id or date as conditions to accomplish the same thing but I really want to try it this way (using `text` as the condition). Can I update the value of an attribute of a row which is `NULL` by querying on that attribute?

Comment: I recommend reading [working with `NULL` values in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
UPDATE x SET text = 'This is funny' WHERE text IS NULL
```

More information about IS NULL and its counter part IS NOT NULL can be found for example from [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null).

Comment: Also use single quotes (') instead of double (")

Comment: Thanks, that's true, no need to have a query that is specific to MySQL's SQL mode.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
UPDATE x SET text = "This is funny" WHERE text IS NULL
```

and make sure the mysql column "text" is set to varchar 256 or mediumtext

Comment: Why would you recommend a specific VARCHAR length or mediumtext without knowing anything about his requirements? All we know is the *minimum* length needs to be 13.

Comment: because if you try to put a string into an int column it will return a 0, so i wanted him to make sure he is putting the proper values in. maybe that was the problem. there is nothing wrong with the query example he gave us, so there must be something wrong with either the way the table is configured or the server side programming is wrong. i.e. php synthax incorrect, pdo extension not loaded. there can be soooo many things wrong.

Comment: My point isn't "int vs string", my point is "text versus mediumtext versus longtext" and "varchar(256) versus varchar(100) versus varchar(20)". You randomly throw out that it should be 256 or medium length without any reasoning.